# Determining the sample size for quality check

Tags: sampling

Suppose that we have a population of 1000 items assigned to multiple classes (one item to one class only). The maximum number of possible classes is 200 and the distribution of items across the classes varies. The task is to check if the classification is correct on a smaller sample.

Some items (10-20%) are selected automatically to be a part of the sample based on predefined criteria (but not on specific class membership).

What is a good methodology for sampling from the remaining 80-90% of the population to obtain a representative sample for quality check?

Comment: I don't understand. You have a *population* of 1,000 and each belongs to one of 200 possible classes. You already sample 100-200, which is 10-20% of the population. What are you hoping to find?\

Comment: Any random sample of any size is automatically "representative."  The issue should concern how *precisely* the properties of a sample can estimate those of its parent population.  So, what properties are you interested in (how do you quantify "quality"?) and how precisely do you need to estimate them?

Comment: @AdamO - The 100-200 items are selected for because there is a flag/signal present (say a keyword  in the item description) that automatically qualifies them for quality audit. The remaining 800-900 items do have such flag/signal but still may be classified incorrectly. I need to sample from those. The total population size remains 1000 items but the ratio of items with audit flag to items with no audit flag changes.

Comment: @whuber - the measure of quality would be precision (TP / (TP + FP)) for each class. How precisely to estimate them - here I was hoping for some advise.

Comment: @J-J-J - I would like to estimate the precision per class using the automatically selected items plus sample from the rest of the items. In regards to how precise the estimate should be I was hoping for some help in how to set it.